# Array of Buffered Readers in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

Is it possible to have an array of Buffered Readers like

```
 BufferedReader[] b = new BufferedReader(5);
```

and Initialise them individually like

```
b[0] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change `BufferedReader()` to `BufferedReader[]` it is possible:

```
BufferedReader[] b = new BufferedReader[5];//<-- correct size declaration of array

b[0] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo"));
```

`BufferedReader(5)` results in a compiler error in your IDE..

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but you're using the wrong syntax to create the array. It should use square brackets to specify the array size instead of parentheses:

```
BufferedReader[] b = new BufferedReader[5];
```